# Config an Android Project in IDEA encountering Gradle problem

Tags: gradle

Get the Error: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.0/gradle-2.3.0.pom'. Received status code 405 from server: Method Not Allowed
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

I cannot solve the problem of whether I am in an offline mode or not. I am expecting to configure the project successfully so that I can compile it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.